# alert for allow or dont allow Apple push notification in iphone application

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am using Apple Push Notification in my application.

when my application is installed on device i want application to ask user if they want allow application to use notification or not, how can i implement so?
something like this application.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do any extra work for that. Just configure your app for push notifications and call:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: types];
```

Comment: Hi, i have done what you said, but even not working, is that because my device's UDID is added to my server's database?

Comment: You really don't need to worry about that. iOS would ask user about that if it needs to.

Comment: Thanks for that, but i tried with removing my Device from server's database even and remove application from iPhone and reinstall it too. but doesn't help. that's why i was worried.

Comment: That's because you already registered your device UDID for notifications. Try to call [[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications] But I repeat again: you should not worry about that alert at all.

Answer (score 0):

This happens automatically when an app asks to register itself for push notifications, just as it does when an app first asks for the device's location. You don't need to do anything special beyond the `-registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` call (as Max mentioned) which you have to make anyway.

Comment: Hi, I'm having APNS issue I was wondering if you can help. You can check my question here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329717/how-to-make-iphone-app-asks-to-register-device-for-push-notification-multiple-tim